# Error installing Sitecore update package

Tags: update-packages

Sitecore 8.2.7. 
Trying to install an update package via `/sitecore/admin/UpdateInstallationWizard.aspx` The package was created using `Sitecore Rocks (1.5.1.8)`.

The package seemed to install okay on one instance of Sitecore, but on another, I get the following error when it tries to install some of the items in the package:

```
Error installing 'addeditems/master/sitecore/content/global/shared/base menu/base parent footer/terms and conditions_{89290570-500b-43e5-b29e-28c2100ad413}'.


Some of the installation operation cannot be performed.
An exception occured when trying to install 'addeditems/master/sitecore/content/global/shared/base menu/base parent footer/terms and conditions_{89290570-500b-43e5-b29e-28c2100ad413}'.
Details: System.InvalidOperationException: incorrect data at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsFalse(Boolean condition, String message) at Sitecore.Update.Utils.ItemUtils.GetRollbackCommandsForCreateParent(String path, String nearestParentPath, Item createdParent, CommandInstallerContext context) in C:\BA\76ddd57e72ab6f2c\code\Sitecore.Update\Update\Utils\ItemUtils.cs:line 59 at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.AddItemCommandInstaller.ItemInstaller.RegisterRollbackOperationForCreateParentCommand(String path, String nearestParentPath, Item createdParent, Database database, CommandInstallerContext context) in C:\BA\76ddd57e72ab6f2c\code\Sitecore.Update\Update\Installer\Items\Installers\Install\AddItemCommandInstaller.cs:line 1479 at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.AddItemCommandInstaller.ItemInstaller.GetParentItem(String itemPath, Database database, SyncItem item, ICommand addCommand, CommandInstallerContext context) in C:\BA\76ddd57e72ab6f2c\code\Sitecore.Update\Update\Installer\Items\Installers\Install\AddItemCommandInstaller.cs:line 1579 at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.AddItemCommandInstaller.ItemInstaller.CreateLightweightItem(SyncItem item, Database database, ICommand addCommand, CommandInstallerContext context) in C:\BA\76ddd57e72ab6f2c\code\Sitecore.Update\Update\Installer\Items\Installers\Install\AddItemCommandInstaller.cs:line 955 at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.AddItemCommandInstaller.ItemInstaller.InstallLightweightItem(PackageEntry entry, SyncItem item, AddItemCommand addCommand, CommandInstallerContext context, String addCommandKey, Item& sitecoreItem) in C:\BA\76ddd57e72ab6f2c\code\Sitecore.Update\Update\Installer\Items\Installers\Install\AddItemCommandInstaller.cs:line 1038 at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.AddItemCommandInstaller.ItemInstaller.DoInstall(AddItemCommand addItemCommand, PackageEntry entry, CommandInstallerContext commandContext) in C:\BA\76ddd57e72ab6f2c\code\Sitecore.Update\Update\Installer\Items\Installers\Install\AddItemCommandInstaller.cs:line 785 at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.AddItemCommandInstaller.DoInstall(ICommand cmd, PackageEntry entry, CommandInstallerContext commandContext) in C:\BA\76ddd57e72ab6f2c\code\Sitecore.Update\Update\Installer\Items\Installers\Install\AddItemCommandInstaller.cs:line 86 at Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.BaseItemCommandInstaller.Put(PackageEntry entry) in C:\BA\76ddd57e72ab6f2c\code\Sitecore.Update\Update\Installer\Items\Installers\BaseItemCommandInstaller.cs:line 121
```

Some of the items in the package install okay.

I Googled and came up with nothing. Any ideas would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: did you try this - https://www.teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com/Blog/sitecore-update-installation-wizard-error-in-sitecore-8-update-3 ?

Comment: @MahendraShekhawat - its not the same error. Weirdly, this has been working previously, just something about this package or something in Sitecore. AFAIK, no configs have changed or anything. I've tried a Clean Database and an Update Links Table too, but still no joy

Comment: @stuartw87 did you ever get a resolution to this? Work out the cause of the problem?

Comment: @Ian - sadly not .. never got to the bottom of it at all; it just seemed to happen randomly with no obvious explanation.